# How to troubleshoot API Call JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, urlsession

I'm making an API call to a Rails server to fetch an array of objects and then display those objects in a SwiftUI view.

When I make this same API call in Postman, it works fine.  I get the response.

When I make this same call in my SwiftUI project, I don't appear to be saving that response to my Models properly or I'm running into an error otherwise.  My server appears to be sending the data fine.  The view loads, but with a blank List and just the navigationTitle of "Your Projects"

Looking for guidance on how to check if my response array is storing data and how to troubleshoot.  The view loads the data from this array and it appears to be empty.

I used quicktype.io to map the model structure out from the server provided JSON in Postman.

Here's the relevant portion of the Model:

```
import Foundation

struct ProjectFetchRequest: Decodable {
let request: [ProjectResponseObjectElement]
}

// MARK: - ProjectResponseObjectElement
struct ProjectResponseObjectElement: Codable, Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let project: Project
let projectType: ProjectType
let inspirations: [JSONAny]
}

// MARK: - Project
struct Project: Codable {
let name: String
let id: Int
let projectType, timeframe, description: String
let currentProgress: Int
let zipcode, status, createdAt, visibility: String
let city, state: String
let title: String
let showURL: String
let thumbnailURL: String
let ownedByLoggedinUser, hasBids, isPublished: Bool
}

// MARK: - ProjectType
struct ProjectType: Codable {
let generalConstructions, landscapes: [GeneralConstruction]?
}

// MARK: - GeneralConstruction
struct GeneralConstruction: Codable {
let id: Int
}

typealias ProjectResponseObject = [ProjectResponseObjectElement]
```

Here's the API call:

```
import Foundation

final class Projectservice {

static let shared = Projectservice()

private init() {}

func fetchProjects(completed: @escaping (Result<[ProjectResponseObjectElement], AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {
        
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/projects") else {
        completed(.failure(.custom(errorMessage:"URL unavailable")))
        return
    }
    
    guard let Accesstoken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-token") else { return }
    guard let client = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "client") else { return }
    guard let uid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail") else { return }
    
    print(Accesstoken)
    print(client)
    print(uid)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue(Accesstoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "access-token")
            request.addValue(client, forHTTPHeaderField: "client")
            request.addValue(uid, forHTTPHeaderField: "uid")
            request.addValue("Bearer", forHTTPHeaderField: "Tokentype")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        guard let projectResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ProjectFetchRequest.self, from: data) else { return }
        completed(.success(projectResponse.request))
        print(projectResponse)
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Here's the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProjectsView: View {

@State private var projectObjects: [ProjectResponseObjectElement] = []

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List(projectObjects){ projectObject in
            ProjectRowView(project: projectObject.project)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Your Projects")
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .onAppear {
        fetchProjects()
    }
}
func fetchProjects() {
    Projectservice.shared.fetchProjects { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success(let projectObjects):
                self.projectObjects = projectObjects
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In general, it's a much better idea to do your async/network calls from an ObservableObject and not inside your view (which in SwiftUI is very transient). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, for the purposes of early testing, I'm keeping the function call from the View.  Once I get it working, I'll refactor and move to a ViewModel.

Comment: But that's the thing -- are you sure that the problems are caused because you're doing the async work in a transient view that's getting reloaded mid-stream?

Comment: `…error == nil else { return }`, why not call your completion handler with a `.failure(error)` instead of return quietly? `try?`, replace with `try` and a `do/catch` again by using `.failure`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I took your advice and made this change:              guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
             let projectResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProjectFetchRequest.self, from: data)
             completed(.success(projectResponse.request))
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }  The error I got:  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @jnpdx Here's the full error I got:  typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @JohnGerard pretty straightforward error, but without seeing the JSON to compare it to your model, it's hard to say what needs to be changed.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks.  I was able to figure it out.  I was trying to pull the data into the struct that wasn't the array.  Answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to declare the top level array struct in the URLSession.

```
import Foundation

final class Projectservice {

static let shared = Projectservice()

private init() {}

func fetchProjects(completed: @escaping (Result<[ProjectResponseObjectElement], AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {
        
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/projects") else {
        completed(.failure(.custom(errorMessage:"URL unavailable")))
        return
    }
    
    guard let Accesstoken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-token") else { return }
    guard let client = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "client") else { return }
    guard let uid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail") else { return }
    
    print(Accesstoken)
    print(client)
    print(uid)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue(Accesstoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "access-token")
            request.addValue(client, forHTTPHeaderField: "client")
            request.addValue(uid, forHTTPHeaderField: "uid")
            request.addValue("Bearer", forHTTPHeaderField: "Tokentype")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
         let projectResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProjectResponseObjectElement].self, from: data)
         completed(.success(projectResponse))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: You still don’t properly handle the situation where the URLSession closure parameter `error` is not nil

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know.  I need to go back and add the correct error handling.  I wanted to get it working first.